# Render circles and change color of the intersection

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working in a simple game for desktop and Android using LibGDX framework. The game spawn some balls that move from one side of the screen to the opposite one. I want to show white circles over a black background but I also want to draw some white texts. My problem with this is that I want to draw the intersection between balls and between balls and text in black. I want something like this:

[image]

Other of my problems is that I'm using [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) to draw the circles and they are too pixelated.

What is the best way to render circles in libGDX (Ill have to render between 1 and 100). Is it possible to get the effect shown in the image?

Comment: For your second question: use `circle(float x, float y, float radius, int segments);` and set the segments higher, until the circle is not pixelated anymore. But most times `Shaperenderer` is used for debug rendering only. You may switch to `SpriteBatch` and use a `Texture`. For your other question i am sorry, but a can't think about a solution. Maybe you need a method to define the Intersecting Area and the you can color it.

Comment: Not sure maybe a kind of shaderprogramm could do this but i am not familiar with it.

Comment: Yeah you would need to use an OpenGL shader, which is a small program that runs on your GPU in openGL. There are plenty of tutorials online to do this sort of thing.